# Is it possible to infer parameter types for overridden methods on a subclass?

Tags: typescript

If I have two classes in TypeScript with a parent/child relationship, I need to write out the types for overridden methods on the child class:

```
class Parent {
    method(a: string, b: string): string {
        return a + b;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    method(a: string, b: string) {
        return 'child ' + a + b;
    }
}
```

If the types don't match, it's an error:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    method(a: number, b: string) {
 // ~~~~~~ Property 'method' in type 'Child' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Parent'.
        return 'child ' + a + b;
    }
}
```

If I don't specify the types, I get implicit any errors:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    method(a, b) {
        // ~  ~  Parameters 'a', 'b' implicitly have 'any' types.
        return 'child ' + a + b;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get TypeScript to infer the types of `a` and `b` without having to copy/paste them from `Parent`?

Comment: Not really, see [Microsoft/TypeScript#1373](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373) for the relevant issue.

Comment: They tried, but [failed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118#issuecomment-216595207).❌

Comment: And here's the [latest (open) issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911).